# Microservices: Parallels computing without counters

Tags: architecture, microservices, distributed-computing, google-cloud-pubsub

### Background

Let's imagine a distributed system, on a microservice architecture, that processing queue messages in parallel. This system has two kinds of applications: `A` and `B`.

`A` is a REST API application that gets requests for processing. Each request is translated into a list of subtasks that solve the request. So, once `A` got a new request, it will insert N messages into the queue of `B` application. N is a dynamic value that being a change for each input request.
Once the processing is completed (all the N items were processed successfully), we will notify the customer (the requestor) about the total result.

### Possible Solution

Assuming a request will have N subtasks to process. Our application `A` will create an atomic counter with the initialized value of N. Each time that application `B` will process a message from the queue, it will decrease the counter by 1 and see its new value.

The last processing will leave the value "0" on the counter. Once the application detected the value "0", application `B` will notify the customer about the result of the processing.

### Problems

The possible solution above has two major downsides:

1. You must have an atomic counter that will sync all the general progress. Without this, you unable to know when the task is completed.
2. Many distributed queues systems, like Google PubSub, have the approach of "At Least Once" delivery ([source](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#at-least-once-delivery)), which means that the same message can be dequeued multiple times from the queue. That eventually will lead to notify the customer before all the queue messages were processed.

### Question

What is the right way to solve the problem above, when using a queue system like Google PubSub?

Comment: The queue is the wrong abstraction for such use cases. Look at an orchestrator like temporal.io that provides direct support for dynamic task coordination.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an atomic counter, the application `B` can't simply put a message on another `task completion queue` that the application `A` consumes? So that only the application `A` keeps track of the progress?

Regarding your question, one approach that you can use to solve that problem would be to keep track of completed jobs, in a DB table. Once the job is completed (all N tasks have been processed), you send the notification to the client, but you also mark in the DB that the job has been completed.

Then, if you dequeue a message which is part of a completed job, you can just ignore it.

Comment: 1. It's possible to make `A` (or even new player, `C`) track the progress - but it demands more resources. Also, atomic counter is mandatory. Unless you define that only one single instance of application is closing the progress - but then you loosing the HA and scaling abilities. 2. Ignoring counter that gets into minus territory leads to notify the customer before the progress is completed (therefore, you don't have the complete answer to notify).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this kind of processing with [Cloud Pub/Sub ordering keys](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/ordering). However, the solution is a bit complex, since, as other commenters have pointed out, queues may not be the best abstraction for this kind of task coordination. [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/dual-overview), [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs), or consolidating work via some form of storage may be better suited for this use case.

One way to do this with Cloud Pub/Sub is to have `A` publish its `N` messages with a single ordering key in a single region, and then publish a "work complete" message on the same ordering key. Cloud Pub/Sub will ensure that these messages arrive at `B` in order. `B` doesn't need to maintain a counter of how many messages it's processed; once it receives a "work complete" message, then it knows it can notify the customer about the result of the processing.

This would ensure that `B` does not notify the customer that the processing is complete before all subtasks have been completed. However, note that due to Cloud Pub/Sub's at-least-once message delivery guarantee, it is still possible for `B` to notify the customer multiple times for the same work unless you do some deduplication in `B`.

Answer (score 0):

It is good to see the different perspectives provided by Lauren and Cosmin. I think they already provided two good approaches with more details need to be worked out.

To elaborate on the right solution, the question does not provide info on how the micro services are deployed and what the high availability requirements are.

A similar solution we designed is to use persistent storage to keep track of the progress of the tasks ( we used database ). It will help in decoupling  the processing of each task and provides flexibility to assign each task to a different node in a cluster on which Microservice B is deployed. Using a persistent storage to track the status of the task execution ( GCS Buckets or a DB ) will provide resilience with processing failures. If a node goes down while processing a task, another node can pickup - by using Pubsub redelivery.

We should check the execution status of each task in the DB or GCP bucket to send the final notification to the customer ( when all the tasks are completed ).